# How to create Blob containing ANSI data instead of UTC-8

Tags: angular, typescript, blob

I have an MVC website that uses a PDF writer toolkit that I wrote.  I'm trying to rewrite the website using Angular.  I have everything working except the process of downloading the PDF file to the user's computer.  This point of failure is creating the Blob object.  It takes the binary ANSI file and converts the data to UTF-8.  How can I create the Blob forcing it to use ANSI/windows-1252 encoding?

**What I've tried:**
"buffer" is the raw PDF data that I get back from my call to the API service.  I need to be able to have this raw data saved to the user's computer.  I have tried creating an "A" tag and programmatically clicking on the "A" link to download the data.  I have also tried using the FileSaver NuGet package.  Both solutions successfully download the file but fail because they are saving the file as utf-8 data instead of ANSI data.  In the debugger, you can plainly see that the buffer data almost doubles when creating the Blog data.  None of the following give me the desired results.

```
const propBag: BlobPropertyBag = { type: "application/pdf"};
//const propBag: BlobPropertyBag = { type: "application/pdf;charset=windows-1252"};
//const propBag: BlobPropertyBag = { type: "text/plain;charset=windows-1252"};
const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], propBag);
```

I have seen posts suggesting it requires a third party tool to convert between UTF-8 and ANSI but while the ones I have seen allow you to convert the text it doesn't solve the issue of storing ANSI data into the Blob as appears to be required when saving the Blob contents to file.  I already have ANSI data.  I just need to be able to save it unchanged to the user's computer.

**Complete method I'm using for testing:**

```
  /**
  * Saves the file on the client's machine via FileSaver library.
  *
  * @param buffer The data that need to be saved.
  * @param fileName File name to save as.
  * @param fileType File type to save as.
  */
  private saveAsPdfFile(buffer: string, fileName: string, fileType: string): void {
    const encoding = 'windows-1252'; // a.k.a ANSI
  
    const propBag: BlobPropertyBag = { type: "application/pdf;charset=windows-1252"};
    //const propBag: BlobPropertyBag = { type: "text/plain;charset=windows-1252"};
    const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], propBag);

    let url = URL.createObjectURL(data);

// Download from link method
    let downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    downloadLink.href = url;
    downloadLink.setAttribute('download', fileName);
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);

// Downloading using FileSaver
    //FileSaver.saveAs(url, fileName);

// Both ways of downloading are saving the pdf but it's being save as UTF-8.
  
// how it worked from MVC application
//     http_response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(filename)
//     http_response['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = "Content-Disposition"
//     HttpResponse.ContentType = "application/pdf";
//     Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=example.pdf");
//     Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
//     pdf.SaveToStream(stream);
//     return stream;  

}
```

Comment: You don't want it to be in ANY character set.  It's raw, 8-bit binary data.  It's not encoded at all.  Where do you think it is being converted?

Comment: This call does the conversion:
const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], propBag);

Comment: It's either being converted there or it's being converted when sending the pdf from the api service to the Angular app.

Comment: PDF actually does specify the encoding to be used.  In my case I'm using WinAnsiEncoding as defined by the PDF specs.  This is important as there is a table in the PDF file that specifies locations of various objects in the PDF document.<br/>

Comment: The solution I randomly found was as follows.  convert the uint8array to a string iterating through the array and using fromCharCode.  Then call the following:
`const propBag: BlobPropertyBag = { type: "application/pdf"};

    const buff = Buffer.from(pdfText, 'ascii');
    const data: Blob = new Blob([buff], propBag);`

Comment: Sorry.  I am not that familiar with the way posting here works and it's giving me issues trying to write a meaningful comment and limiting me as to how long it takes.  Hopefully what I have written makes sense.  Thank you for your help!